# Extracting library directories from a long variable

Tags: regular-expression

I declared a long variable containing the libraries to use during the compilation:

```
export LIBS="-L/usr/lib -lcurl -L/lib -lhdf5 -Wl,-rpath,/lib -L/usr/lib64 -lglpk -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/tools/vtk-6.1.0/lib -L/usr/local/tools/vtk-6.1.0/lib -lvtkIOCore-6.1 -lvtkCommonCore-6.1 -lvtkCommonDataModel-6.1 -lvtkFiltersCore-6.1 -lvtkIOXML-6.1 -lvtkImagingCore-6.1 -lvtkIOImage-6.1 -lvtkImagingMath-6.1 -lz -L/g/g92/miguel/petsc-3.6.2/miguel-opt/lib -lpetsc -Wl,-rpath,/g/g92/miguel/petsc-3.6.2/miguel-opt/lib -lcmumps -ldmumps -lsmumps -lzmumps -lmumps_common -lpord -lscalapack -lHYPRE -L/usr/local/tools/openmpi-intel-1.8.4/lib -L/usr/local/tools/ic-14.0.174/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -lml -llapack -lblas -lparmetis -lmetis -lX11 -lhwloc -lssl -lcrypto -lmpi_usempif08 -lmpi_usempi_ignore_tkr -lmpi_mpifh -lifport -lifcore -lm -lmpi -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/tools/ic-14.0.174/lib -limf -lsvml -lirng -lipgo -ldecimal -lcilkrts -lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lirc -lpthread -lirc_s -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/tools/openmpi-intel-1.8.4/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/tools/ic-14.0.174/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/g/g92/miguel/code/libmesh_2D/lib -L/g/g92/miguel/code/libmesh_2D/lib -lmesh_opt"
```

Now I would like to extract the directories that start with -L. I tried doing this:

```
printenv LIBS | grep -o '\b-L\w*'
```

but I do not obtain any result, whereas doing this (just for trying to understand what is going on)

```
printenv LIBS | grep -o '\b-l\w*'
```

extracts only the words "-linux" in my variable. 
I would like to obtain as a result a new variable that were like this:

/usr/lib /lib /usr/lib64-lglpk /usr/local/tools/vtk-6.1.0/lib ...

I obviously do not understand much about regular expressions and I often feel confused with the different tools used (grep, sed, awk, etc) and the answers that show an encryptic regexp with no explanation whatsoever. Could I have a useful reference please? Is the regexp syntax universal across the above mentioned different tools? Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: Check the update on my answer: actually there *is* a safe way to parse that string, but only as long as the spaces in the paths are escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the definition of word boundary:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, **if the first character is a word character**.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

No word boundary can match in between a non-word character and a dash, because a dash is not a word character either.

Also since e.g. slashes are non-word characters as well, and **since you don't have spaces in the paths**, rather than matching `\w*` it would me more sensitive to match `[^ ]*`. *However*, since you also want to exclude part of the match, `grep` is not the right tool for the job, unless you're using a `grep` version which supports PCREs:

```
printenv LIBS | grep -Po '(^| )-L[^ ]*'
```

```
% printenv LIBS | grep -Po '(^| )-L\K/[^ ]*'
/usr/lib
/lib
/usr/lib64
/usr/local/tools/vtk-6.1.0/lib
/g/g92/miguel/petsc-3.6.2/miguel-opt/lib
/usr/local/tools/openmpi-intel-1.8.4/lib
/usr/local/tools/ic-14.0.174/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/compiler/lib/intel64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7
/g/g92/miguel/code/libmesh_2D/lib
```

However this relies on the paths not containing spaces, and relying on the paths not containing dashes would be just as wrong.

<del>Generally, there's no safe way to parse that string.</del>

<del>My suggestion is to store the paths into an array manually.</del>

On a second thought, I guess potential spaces in a path would be escaped in order for the path to be interpreted correctly?

If that's the case, this would be safe:

```
printenv LIBS | grep -Po '(^| )-L\K\/.*?(?=([^\\] |$))'
```

```
% export LIBS='-L/path\ with\ spaces -L/another\ path\ with\ spaces'
% printenv LIBS | grep -Po '(^| )-L\K\/.*?(?=([^\\] |$))'
/path\ with\ space
/another\ path\ with\ spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $LIBS | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /^-L/){print $i} } }'
```

grep works with lines, as sed does. awk works with fields. for such task, I'd prefer to use awk, however grep or sed could do the job as well.

Comment: Thanks, but how would you remove the -L from the output?

Comment: `|sed -e 's/^-L//'`

Comment: The pitfall being a path with a space, which would be printed only partially. Or printed only partially and followed by a nonsense in case of a path such as `/usr/lib/my\ -Library/`. I suggest you make this clear in the answer.